# What is the downside of loading too many packages?

Tags: r

I've been working on a fairly big research project with lots of sub-parts. I have created an `R` script for each sub-part so I don't get lost with one single script that is loo long.

**My question** is what is the best practice regarding the loading of libraries in large projects like this?

*Here is what I do:* Instead of calling specific libraries at the start of each sub-parts, I have created a separate script that loads all libraries that are necessary for the entire project and I call this script at the beginning of each sub-part.

What happens is that sometimes I'm working a sub-part of the project that does not need, for example, `ggplot2` and some other libraries. What is the downside of loading many libraries in `R` that you're not necessarily using a that moment?

Here is a small sample of my `LoadPackages.R` script. Note that this script is meant to be used in a project shared with other users, so I find it important to make sure all libraries are properly installed:

```
# List of packages to install
  list.of.packages <- c("sp", "rgeos", "ggplot2", "data.table", "rgdal", "dplyr", 
                        "magrittr", "spatialEco", "geosphere", "readr")

# Only install packages not installed yet
  new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
  if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)

# Load packages
  library(sp)
  library(rgeos)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(data.table)
  library(dplyr)
  library(magrittr)
  library(readr)
  library(spatialEco)
  library(geosphere)
  library(rgdal)

# clean global env.
  rm(new.packages, list.of.packages)
  gc(reset = T)
```

At the beginning of each work session, I load all libraries by running:

```
source("./R scripts/LoadPackages.R")
```

Comment: One downside is that packages can mask functions from other packages or even base R. Hadley in particular is known to have no compunction against doing that with his packages.

Comment: Rather than creating objects in the global environment and then `rm`’ing them, you should consider putting the relevant code into a `local({…})` expression. That’s what it’s there for.

Comment: Why load `data.table`, `dplyr`, `magrittr` & `readr`? I wouldn't be surprised that only `data.table` would be enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple downsides. In rough order of severity:

1. **It makes it harder to reason about code**. Code is complex. Robust code is therefore  *as simple as possible*. This is a well-established fact in software engineering, and also just common sense. An important part of this is to limit the number of symbols that are visible at any given point in the program: if there are 1000 symbols visible at state X, this means that, in order to prove things about the state X (= know what’s going on at X), I need to reason about up to 1000 symbols and their interactions. This is clearly impossible. And so bugs creep in.
2. **The more dependencies you add, the more you increase the risk of your code breaking over time**, because each dependency individually has a given risk of breaking due to updates introducing incompatibilities. Additionally, the risk of this happening increase *supralinearly* for two reasons: (a) direct dependencies have *transitive* dependencies that may also break; and (b) dependencies interact in ways that may introduce incompatibilities. Keeping the list of dependencies smaller makes code drastically more robust. This doesn’t mean that you should instead reimplement the functionality of other packages in your own code (though it *might* mean that, in rare cases) but it means consciously choosing dependencies.
3. Related to (1), **attaching many packages leads to name clashes**, because different packages *will* use the same names. This isn’t a problem in itself, and is just a natural consequence of how language works: descriptive names are sometimes reused in different domains. Unfortunately R is quite bad at coping with identical names from different packages. Best not to let the situation arise.
4. **Loading packages can be slow**. This alone should be a reason to only load the packages you need. I don’t know about all the packages you’re using, but some packages (especially in Bioconductor) can take up to 10 seconds to load.

Generally, **I’d advise strongly against the practice of loading packages unnecessarily**. For the same reason I’m also not a fan of the ‹tidyverse› package: it may be handy for interactive exploration to load all tidyverse packages in one go, but it decreases maintainability and goes against established practice in virtually any other programming community.

Comment: Note that Konrad has a modules package, https://github.com/klmr/modules (not to be confused with the CRAN modules package) that can help here.  Alternately you can create R packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Konrad, much appreciated and I agree with your points. I don't understand though why you say that 'It makes it harder to reason about code'. One reason that led to adopt my approach was precisely to have more clear easy-to ready scripts with all my `library(xxx)` commands in a separate file.

Comment: @rafa.pereira Think of your code as a mathematical proof, or a system of equations, where every symbol (variable, function …) represents a variable. Your task is to solve this system of equations, or to recapitulate the proof. The more variables there are, the harder this will be. In fact, if there are more than a few, it will become completely impossible. Every `library` call adds symbols. You therefore would like that, at any given point in your code, there are as few libraries attached as possible. Unfortunately R makes this hard in general (because libraries usually *stay* attached).